# Can I see how many mission items I've found during the current mission?

Tags: dishonored

You can view how many bone shards, paintings and runes you've found when you are done with your mission. Can I view how much of the items I've already found while doing the mission?

Comment: It shows "x/y collected" when you puck one up. Not sure if you can check in the abstract though.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that already. I was idd looking for a way too check it in the menu.

Comment: Which is why I left that as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I know... just wanted to know that I had figured out the same as you.

Comment: I do not know about bone charms, runes, and paintings but you can look in  your inventory to see the number of blueprints you have. Of course this does not tell you how many are in the level, just the number you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

You can't see it in the menu or anywhere else. The only things you see is:

- If you find one collectable, it will display your **total** amount of collectables from this type in the bottom line.
- If your done with the level, it will provide a summary of all found collectables and those which could be found in the level.

But you can take a look at a list of collectables per level to get the info early enough and just remember how much you already found in a specific level. Such a list can be found [here](http://www.trueachievements.com/dishonored-walkthrough.htm?page=5).